# How can i validate multiple XML records in a single file using XSD schema in C#?

Tags: xsd

I am new to XML. I have a file with multiple XML records in it as shown below:

```
<event> //Record 1
 <sequence>1</sequence>
 <date>5-Feb-2012</date>
 <time>00:00:42</time>
 <severity>0</severity>
 <errorcode>0</errorcode>
</event>
<event> //Record 2
 <sequence>2</sequence>
 <date>5-Feb-2012</date>
 <time>00:00:51</time>
 <severity>0</severity>
 <errorcode>0</errorcode>
</event>
```

I need to validate this input file. I have written a schema as given below:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="event">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="sequence" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="date" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="time" type="xs:time"/>
            <xs:element name="severity" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="errorcode" type="xs:integer"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This works if i have only one record in the file and throws exception saying "there are multiple root elements".

Answer (score 0):

It's like the exception said: an XML document can only have a single root element. You need something like this:

```
<root>
    <event></event>
    <event></event>
</root>
```

Comment: Hi John.. Thanks for the reply. Is there anyway to work out without modifying the file ?

Comment: I've never tried it before, but you can try creating an `XmlReader` by using `XmlReader.Create(source, new XmlReaderSettings {ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment});` This should read one fragment, but I don't know if it will read more than one.